# How can I write a Function A to call Function B, and Function B call Function A without finish function A , infinite loop this?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function B()
    {
        alert('2');
        A();
    }

    function A()
    {
        alert('1');
        B();
    }
</script>

<html>
<body onload="A();">
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to use javascript to do that without jQuery? In my script, A can call B, but B can't call A? I don't know why B can't call A in my script. I'm not sure that is because A hasn't finished so that B can't call A right now. A>B>A>B>A>B makes an infinte loop. Can I do the above result in some way?

Comment: I didn't really understand: you want an infinite loop, or not?

Comment: According to this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BGtzj/ it works fine

Comment: @koopajah: You might want to link to a actual fiddle, instead of the site itself ;-)

Comment: Awesome, infinite `alert` loops!

Comment: acually I am not to make infinite alert

Comment: How about I want to loop my two video?

Comment: For your information, what you are trying to achieve is called mutual recursion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)

Comment: Why do you mention jQuery at all? It is just a library of functions, written in JS itself and can never do anything JS can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) functions. they'r working asynchronously.

```
function B()
{
    alert('2');
    setTimeout(A, 1);
    alert('3');
}

function A()
{
    alert('1');
    setTimeout(B, 1);
}
```

in function B javascript will wait for 1 millisecond and call function A, but it will also continue executing your code in B so '3' will be alerted and B will be ended before calling A

Comment: Can you help me to fix this problem?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699116/how-to-play-two-different-source-video-when-one-end-then-switch-to-the-next-on