# How to play two different source video, when one end, then switch to the next one and loop the step?

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sequential Movies</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // listener function changes src
        function myNewSrc() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.src = "2.m4v";
            myVideo.load();
            myVideo.play();
        myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myAddListener, false);
        }
        // add a listener function to the ended event

        function myAddListener(){
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        myVideo.src = "1.m4v";
            myVideo.load();
            myVideo.play();
            myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myAddListener()">
    <video controls
           src="1.m4v">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems the problem is video1 can switch to video2, but video2 can't switch back to video1.
How can I write a script to loop 1 > 2 > 1 > 2 > 1 > 2 > 1?
IS it possible to switch more than three video source?
I don't know what the bottom link talking about but it seems useful to help me.

[play next video in an array on "ended"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668399/play-next-video-in-an-array-on-ended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you add two listeners to the same video object. You can use something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sequential Movies</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var videoSources = ["SSR-Styles.mp4","Gauges-radial.mp4"]
        var currentIndex = 0;

        function setFirstVideo()
    {
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    }

    function videoEnded(){
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % videoSources.length;
            myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
            myVideo.load();
            myVideo.play();
        }    
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setFirstVideo()">
    <video controls  onended="videoEnded()"
           src="">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This wil automatically loop through the 2 video's:

```
var id = 1; // Current video number
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
myVideo.addEventListener("ended", myNewSrc)

function myNewSrc() {
    myVideo.src = id+".m4v";
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
    id++ % 2 + 1; // Set ID to the other number
}
```

In your html:

```
<body onload="myNewSrc()">
```